# Xamarin.Forms Dropdown aka Spinner

Tags: c#, xamarin, spinner, xamarin.forms, dropdown

Im porting Web APP to a Xamarin.Forms application
im now facing a problem that i can't realy find on the net..

How can i create a dropdown in Xamarin.Forms since there is no option for it
i tried to use Compiler directives like:

```
        #if __ANDROID__
         Android.Widget.Spinner dropdown = new Android.Widget.Spinner(this);
        #endif
```

The thing is i dont have Android.Content.Context since im in Xamarin.Forms.
how can i achieve this to make a spinner aka dropdown in my Xamarin.Forms app.

Thanks in Advance.
Stefan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [Picker](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/) when the user can select between pre defined values.